# Get value of JSON object using jq --stream

Tags: json, stream, jq

I'm trying to extract the value of an JSON object using `jq --stream`, because the real data can the size of multiple GigaBytes.

This is the JSON I'm using for my tests, where I want to extract the value of `item`:

```json
{
  "other": "content here",
  "item": {
    "A": {
      "B": "C"
    }
  },
  "test": "test"
}
```

The `jq` options I'm using:

```sh
jq --stream --null-input 'fromstream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "item"))[]' example.json
```

However, I don't get any output with this command.

A strange thing I found is that when removing the object after the `item` the above command seems to work:

```json
{
  "other": "content here",
  "item": {
    "A": {
      "B": "C"
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks as expected:

```
❯ jq --stream --null-input 'fromstream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "item"))[]' example.json
{
  "A": {
    "B": "C"
  }
}
```

But as I cannot control the input JSON this is not the solution.

I'm using jq version 1.6 on MacOS.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that works, but isn't feasible as the real data is multiple GigaBytes in size, which results in out of memory issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't truncate the stream, therefore after filtering it to only include the parts below `.item`, `fromstream` is missing the final back-tracking item `[["item"]]`. Either add it manually at the end (not recommended, this would also include the top-level object in the result), or, much simpler, use `1 | truncate_stream` to strip the first level altogether:

```sh
jq --stream --null-input '
  fromstream(1 | truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "item")))
' example.json
```

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": "C"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `reduce` and `setpath` to build up the result object yourself:

```sh
jq --stream --null-input '
  reduce inputs as $in (null;
    if $in | .[0][0] == "item" and has(1) then setpath($in[0];$in[1]) else . end
  )
' example.json
```

```json
{
  "item": {
    "A": {
      "B": "C"
    }
  }
}
```

To remove the top level object, either filter for `.item` at the end, or, similarly to `truncate_stream`, remove the path's first item using `[1:]` to strip the first level:

```sh
jq --stream --null-input '
  reduce inputs as $in (null;
    if $in | .[0][0] == "item" and has(1) then setpath($in[0][1:];$in[1]) else . end
  )
' example.json
```

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": "C"
  }
}
```